# Как реализовать переключение блоков с помощью css?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, css-grid

В шаблоне имеется 3 блока и снизу справа стрелочки [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

возможно ли реализовать переключение между блоками  при нажатии на стрелочки с помощью css?

Comment: Если у вас всего 3 блока и все они видны, то зачем вам переключалка? А подсветку можно hover ом сделать.

Comment: я  это все понимаю, но макет такой возможно блоков может быть больше)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласен с комментарием под вопросом, но если нужно [вот примерная реализация](https://codepen.io/13-friday/pen/QWwgVoE?editors=1100)

```
<div class="CSSgal">

  <s id="s1"></s> 
  <s id="s2"></s>
  <s id="s3"></s>
  <s id="s4"></s>

  <div class="slider">
    <div style="background:#000;">
            <h2>Slide 1</h2>
        </div>
    <div style="background:#000;">
            <h2>Slide 2</h2>
        </div>
    <div style="background:#000;">
            <h2>Slide 3</h2>
        </div>
  </div>

  <div class="prevNext">
    <div><a href="#s4"></a><a href="#s2"></a></div>
    <div><a href="#s1"></a><a href="#s3"></a></div>
    <div><a href="#s2"></a><a href="#s4"></a></div>
  </div>

  <div class="bullets">
    <a href="#s1">1</a>
    <a href="#s2">2</a>
    <a href="#s3">3</a>
  </div>

</div>
```